# Joomla module classes duplicating/nesting

Tags: html, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

My module position in my Joomla template is just a div with a "row" class. When I add content to that module position using the custom html module and give it module class suffixes of "first", "mod-light" and "bord-left"it appears to nest 2 divs within my module position both with the same classes which is causing problems. How do I modify this so that it is not creating this nested structure or at least does not apply these classes to the inner div?

For example, if I simply entered this raw html into the editor...

```
"<p>...entered content appears here...</p>"
```

I would get this output from Joomla...

```
<div class="moduletable first mod-light bord-left span4">
    <div class="custom first mod-light bord-left">
    <p>...entered content appears here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make Joomla do this instead...

```
<div class="moduletable first mod-light bord-left span4">

    <p>...entered content appears here...</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom module chrome to create your own module layouts:

http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome

Comment: Thank you, this goes some way to helping me, however, it seems that the content that I enter in the editor is output in the module as "echo $module->content;" and the suffixes, bootstrap size choices and modules style choice are applied to the div that it is wrapped in. However, the Module Title is not contained within that "content" variable and so outputs outside of the div however I edit the modules.php. That means that I cannot have a single wrapper for both without it inheriting the same classes - a problem when I am applying a visible border since both the title and the box are bordered

Comment: Fixed: I needed to do a layout overrride for mod_custom which involved removing all extraneous piffle-paffle and simply echoing the content... <?php echo $module->content;?>
Thank you for your help - it did lead to me finding a solution